# Element query global performance

Tags: android, iphone, performance, responsive-design, media-queries

I just checked the [element queries](https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries) concept, it seems very interesting. I would like to use this concept on a new responsive project I have on front of me. I've tested this on several devices but you never can be sure.

I would like to know if somebody has used it and has had a real performance experience.

My project will cover IE9+, last version of modern browsers (FF, CH, SA, OP), ipad (Last IOS), iphone  (Last IOS) and android 4.1+.

Is this safe to use? Any issues on its performance?

[Further explanation of element queries](http://ianstormtaylor.com/media-queries-are-a-hack/)

Comment: I have a much more performant, accurate, and reliable mechanism on the way (writing a blog post about it right now), I'll post the answer here shortly.

Comment: @csuwldcat ummm thank you very much!!! I just want to be sure before using it for real.

Comment: I have posted the answer with a performant element query solution - let me know what you think!

Comment: If you’re still looking for an alternative, I also created an element query script which should be quite performant: https://github.com/ausi/cq-prolyfill

Answer (score 1):

As promised, I am posting a more performant solution to the problem of element queries. Using the setup below, you can do element queries on any element. This solution enables the full Media Query API to be used on individual elements. You'll need to grab the script/style package here: http://www.backalleycoder.com/2014/04/18/element-queries-from-the-feet-up/ - the post also contains a full deep-dive (that I recommend you read before use) on the mechanism used to accomplish it, and another implementation option.

Here's the markup/syntax you'll use, notice the `media=""` attribute:

**HTML**

```
<section media="query(small-width, (max-wodth: 300px))">

  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>

</section>
```

When queries are matched, the query id will appear in the `matched-media=""` attribute - you'll use that to target styles for the corresponding query:

**CSS**

```
section[matched-media~="small-width"] {
  font-size: 50%; /* small text for a wee lil element! */
}

/* Multiple matches example: */

section[matched-media~="small-width medium-height"] {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Intersting info! Have you tested this cross-browser? What about HTML5 validation?